# Signout User in Server Side Flow of Google+

Tags: servlets, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using **Google+ SignIn** in my website, and utilizing **server-side** SignIn flow, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#using_one-time-code_flow).
After sending `token` to my server, i manage the *User Session*, by my own code and *SignIn button or Script*, doesn't appear in subsequent pages.

However, i have a `logout button`, that takes user out, but i don't know how to **logout** him, from **Google+** at same time, preferably on my logut page.

**NOTE:** I want to logout user from *my app*, not the Google Services.

Answer (score 0):

We don't think it's a good experience for your site to be able to log the user out of all Google services. Consider how annoying it would be for a user if all of their Google tabs (like GMail and Youtube) stopped working because they clicked a button your site.

We think you should offer a logout button that logs the user out of just your site.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question as its not clear. I dont want to log him out of Google but only from my app.

Comment: You can log them out of your app using gapi.auth.signOut(): https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#sign-out

Comment: That is known to me, but the task is how to initiate this function after new Page arrives (after my internal logout)

Comment: Use gapi.auth.signOut() first then execute your internal logout.

Comment: But, i don't refer the JS Lib internally on my Page. Its only on my Login and Logout Page.

Comment: But, i don't refer the JS Lib internally on my Page. Its only on my Login and Logout Page.

Comment: I suggest that when the user clicks logout on your logout page you should call gapi.auth.signOut() then trigger your own logout. This way you'll only need to refer to our JS library on your login and logout pages.

Comment: Using that Lib actually triggers a new Auth on every page. I solved it using a server side HTTP request to Google endpoint and expirinng the token and then logout me.

Comment: @VikasRaturi What Google endpoint did you use to expire your token?  I am also trying to logout from Google Auth server-side and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JMTyler: Not sure. Things have changed much and project is no longer now. You may get help at bottom of page [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#revoking-access-to-a-token-or-application). Link seems to be broken though.